# How to use the ViewModel-First approach?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm

Is there any framework that facilitates this approach without much hassle?

It seems frameworks like MVVM Light are more view-first focused.

Comment: Caliburn Micro works well for VM first. I don't know enough about the others.

Comment: Why would you ever need a viewmodel-first approach? A model-first approach (i.e. Domain Driven Design) I can understand, and indeed I use that all the time with MVVM Lite. But viewmodel-first? That's just asking for trouble down the track when you discover that it doesn't interface well with your business layer and DAL.

Comment: @MarkFeldman - this is not about model design but about (GUI) composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah. There are many frameworks to build MVVM applications:

- `MVVM Light` and `Caliburn.Micro`. They are relatively simple and lightweight. It wouldn't take you long to get up and running.
- `Prism` is really cool framework. However, it will take more time to learn, than the above frameworks. However, you can build really a big application divided on modules.
- `Catel` is not just an MVVM toolkit. As it also includes user controls and lots of enterprise library classes.

**Update:**

My opinion is that it is not their deal of these frameworks to emphasize `ViewModel First` or `View First` approach and these frameworks don't create any hassles when you use `ViewModel First` or `View First` approach. Even if you've chosen `ViewModel First` approach and you want to change this approach to `View First` approach, then there will be no hassles.

In my view these frameworks are designed for these goals:

- Avoiding implementation `INotifyPropertyChanged`(just use built-in implementations(`ViewModelBase` in **MVVMLight** and `BindableBase` in **Prism**))
- Simplifying changing views between modules(in **Prism** is `IRegion.RequestNavigate(...);` )
- Communicating between `viewModels`(`IEventAggregator` in **Prism** and `MessengerInstance.Send(payload, token);` in **MVVMLight**). You do not to have to write your code. There are already created tested code for you in these frameworks.
- Dependency Injection. You can decouple implementations of `Views` from their `ViewModels` through interface.

and the above list is not complete

Comment: But which of them emphasize VM first?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Caliburn.Micro is definitely a VM-first framework. I don't know about others.